# Get Promise Data and store it to a variable to be sent for EJS template

Tags: node.js, ejs, es6-promise

Final task: Display api search results on a EJS template.

Process: Using request and promise, I have the data on a promise of my search api call data.

Problem: How do I pass the string data of the “Promise” into my EJS template?

- Promise only lets me access it via 
  ‘search-api-results-received.then(result_i_need=>console.log(result_i_need)’. I can see it printed but I need it on a variable to pass it on to template.

I tried doing (result_i_need => temp_var_defined_outside = result_i_need) No luck!

Really struggling and pulling my hair. Any help appreciated. Thanks

```
var params = {
  method: "POST",
  uri: `http://api.somewebsite.com/content/search/v1?apiKey=${
    process.env.API_KEY
  }`,
  body: JSON.stringify({
    queryString: req.query.find,
  }),
};

const rp = require("request-promise");
call_search_api = rp(params)
  .then(a => (call_search_api = a))
  .catch(er => console.log("err" + er));
// const call_search_api = searchlib(params,postData).then(a=>console.log(a));
var result = call_search_api.resolve(call_search_api);


res.render('search', {apidata: call_search_api});
```

Inside EJS template

```
<% var total_pages = apidata.results.length; %>
```

Comment: You'll have to wait for the promise to resolve before rendering your template. Please show us your current code.

Comment: i can only access it via console log on the .then() call of a promise. Edit: Added code snippet

Comment: That's still not showing how you're building your EJS template.

Comment: I need access to the API_data on my EJS template. How else can I pass it, so it can be displayed on the page. apidata is a JSON object so I would be looping through it, but that's trivial.

Comment: he is making an EJS template AKX, and the problem is that he is not storing the response of the api.

Comment: try to use https, that is much easier and friendly !!

Comment: @SaadSohail OP can be making an EJS template in a stand-alone script, or they might be using Express.js. I'm asking for the wrapping code to see how to best resolve the promise before rendering things.

Comment: Sorry, I am using Express to create my routes

Comment: @AKX he is using the express.js for the routing and then he is using the EJS template for the client side!! i knew this because i am doing the same jobfrom last 2 year !!!

Comment: @user3547204 Okay. Please show us the full Express view function then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since you're using Express, good news is this isn't hard. Express doesn't really care where you call `res.render()`, so long as you do call it... So put it in the API `.then()` function:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

app.get("/something", (req, res) => {
  const params = {
    method: "POST",
    uri: `http://api.somewebsite.com/content/search/v1?apiKey=${
      process.env.API_KEY
    }`,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      queryString: req.query.find,
    }),
  };

  rp(params)
    .then(apidata => {
      res.render("search", { apidata });
      res.end();
    })
    .catch(er => {
      console.log("err" + er);
      res.end(); // TODO: better error handling
    });
});
```

Better yet, if you can use `async` functions:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");

app.get("/something", async (req, res) => {
  const params = {/* ... as above ... */};

  const apidata = await rp(params);
  res.render("search", { apidata });
  // TODO: missing error handling
});
```

Comment: Yes, i needed the bit where I call render from apidata=> {res.render("search"). Thanks, sorted!